# Rails and Active Model Serializers: prevent double JSON encoding and escape characters (\)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, active-model-serializers

In one of my controllers I manually assemble my JSON data to be able to use AMS custom serializers:

```
data[:foos] = {}
Foo.find(foo_ids).each do |f|
  data[:foos][f.id.to_s] = render_to_string :json => f, :root => false, :serializer => FooCustomSerializer
end

data[:moos] = {}
Moo.find(moo_ids).each do |f|
  data[:moos][f.id.to_s] = render_to_string :json => f, :root => false, :serializer => MooCustomSerializer
end

result = {:system => system_info, :content => data}

respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: result }
end
```

It works, but the problem is it encodes twice the Moos and Foos, and the JSON rendered has plenty of escaped characters:

```
{ "system":"OK",
  "content":
    "foos":"[{\"name\":\"Rex\",\"breed\":\"Lab\"},{\"name\":\"Spot\",\"breed\":\"Dalmation\"},{\"name\":\"Fido\",\"breed\":\"Terrier\"}]"
    ...
```

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Just put `.to_json` after the hash variable.

Example:

```
format.json { render json: result }
# Change to
format.json { render json: result.to_json }
```